# How to change title of Chart Control

Tags: c#

i want to change my `Chart Control` title:

```
    Title title = chart1.Titles.Add("Test");
    Series s = new Series();
    s.Color = Color.Blue;
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    s.BorderWidth = 3;

    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.8, 3.2));
    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.83, 6.5));
    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.9, 12.9));
    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 25.8));
    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.1, 29));
    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.2, 54.8));
    s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.4, 58.1));

    chart1.Series.Add(s);
    chart1.Series.Add(s);

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 4;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
```

Currently the title that i want to change is `Series1`
i have tried `Title title = chart1.Titles.Add("Test")` but `Series1` title still exists.

[image]

Edit:

After:

```
s.Legend = "DifferentLegend";
chart1.Series.Add(s);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the 'Legend' property of the series, something like this:

```
chart1.Series.Add(s);
chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("DifferentLegend"));
chart1.Legends["DifferentLegend"].DockToChartArea = "Default";
chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "DifferentLegend";
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
```

The Title is something different - that's what appears at the top of the chart.

There must also be code for this chart that you're not showing, because I can't see 'Traffic rate' being set anywhere in your code!

For further information on setting Legends, see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @user3271698: Try the updated version above. It's all in the docs if you follow the link. Best of luck.

Comment: Now the table is smaller, only in the right half side and still Series1 exist

Comment: I think there might be something going on in your other code that's affecting this code - I'd suggest you try in the debugger - step through, take a look at what's happening. The MS docs in the link are quite comprehensive too.

Comment: My code didn't touch the table except the code i have provided, BTW your last code just make the table to disapear